# Is there an R function to iteratively change values based on the next column?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that consists of unique identifiers for a group of raters and ratees. I would like to be able to get the interrater reliability for each item but am running into a problem with how the data is structured. Because each ratee was rated 4-5 times I am able to group the data by ratee ID. Unfortunately, because of the unique rater ID, I can't set up the dataset properly to use the irr package.

My data looks something like this

| Rater | Ratee | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 12345 | 1 |
| 12112 | 12345 | 1 |
| 12232 | 12345 | 0 |
| 12457 | 12345 | 0 |
| 16794 | 12345 | 1 |
| 55555 | 16454 | 0 |
| 66666 | 16454 | 1 |
| 77777 | 16454 | 1 |
| 88888 | 16454 | 0 |
| 99999 | 16454 | 1 |

I would like to have some way to iteratively go through each group and rename the unique identifier for the rater to something I can use to pivot the data into the right format. For example, going through each group of ratee ID's and assigning a new value to the rater like r1 for the first value, r2 for the second value and so on, and repeat once it finds a new group. The end result would hopefully look something like this:

| Rater | Ratee | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | 12345 | 1 |
| r2 | 12345 | 1 |
| r3 | 12345 | 0 |
| r4 | 12345 | 0 |
| r5 | 12345 | 1 |
| r1 | 16454 | 0 |
| r2 | 16454 | 1 |
| r3 | 16454 | 1 |
| r4 | 16454 | 0 |
| r5 | 16454 | 1 |

Can anyone help me do this? I am at a loss and have exhausted my R repertoire.

Comment: In your example r1 seems to be associated with ID `11111` and then `55555`. What is the logic here? Is it based on the order of entries and irrespective of the contents of the column? Or is there some connection between the original ID and pseudonymous ID?

Comment: Great question. I'd like to pivot this data so that the values from the rater column become the headers of 5 new columns containing the data from the construct. The new names are there so that the data will (in my mind) be seperated out correctly based on the ratee ID so I can analyze the reliability using the irr package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  group_by(Ratee) %>%
  mutate(new_rater_column = paste0("r", row_number())) %>%
  ungroup()
```

I used a new column name instead of overwriting the old `Rater` column just in case the information there is useful.

Comment: Almost the same thing loaded on my end, I was going to use ```mutate(Rater = paste0("r",1:n()))```

Comment: That worked in a remarkably elegant way! Thank you!